# App crashing by pressing buttons in activity bar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, import

I'm new in Android Studio. The problem is that, when I start the app and press a button in the activity bar, it crashes.

This is my main activity:

```
package com.example.tirir_000.iavq;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AdmisionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        NavigationView navigationView = null;
        Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            InicioFragment fragment = new InicioFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            AdmisionFragment fragment = new AdmisionFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            CarrerasFragment fragment = new CarrerasFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            ComunidadFragment fragment = new ComunidadFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            SgaFragment fragment = new SgaFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    }
```

My logcat says this:

```
 Process: com.example.tirir_000.iavq, PID: 31097
     java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.tirir_000.iavq.MainActivity@659c204 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at com.example.tirir_000.iavq.InicioFragment.onAttach(InicioFragment.java:83)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1231)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1085)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:976)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What error you are getting, Paste your stack trace here.

Comment: *must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener*

Comment: how i implement OnFragmentInteractionListener?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you did not in last you use onFragmentInteraction but you didn't implememt onFragmentInteraction in you Java class

Like this you have to do

Public class xyz extends AppcompactActivity implent onFragmnetInteraction

Do this

Comment: Or just remove your last override method because you are not using that